How to intercept the click on picture in UITextView in iOS 17?
There is a picture in a UITextView, I want to intercept the user's click event, but I found that the function textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool is not called, it is deprecated from iOS 17.The app crashes when click the image, is there a solution to resolve that issue?
I have tried this function func textView(_ textView: UITextView, primaryActionFor textItem: UITextItem, defaultAction: UIAction) -> UIAction?, but when I read the textItem.content, the App crashed, I don't know why, is there anyone have this issue?
